# Example of subring in $\mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_3$ that's not an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_3$ and $S=\{(n,n): n \in\mathbb Z_3\}.$

I'm skipping the step of proving $S$ is a subring of $R$ for now.

Then, let $ x=(1,1)$ and $r=(2,0)$,  then, 
$x*r=(2,0) $ which is not in $S$. Then we know that $S$ is a subring but not an ideal. Is this example concrete? Thank you for the help

Comment: Yes, this example is concrete. Generically, $(n,n)*(a,b)$ where $a\neq b$ won't be in $S$, as this will be $(an,bn)$.  We have that $an\neq bn$ when $a\neq b$, as $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a field, and thus a domain, so we have cancellation.  So $(n,n)*(a,b)\not\in S$.

Comment: This example is correct.

Comment: A ring $R$ of _characteristic_ $p$ always has $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ as subring. So unless $R= \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ and $p$ is prime this will give you a nice example.